# Sort variable according to multiple regex substrings

Tags: r, regex, sorting, substring

I am trying to order a variable in R which is a list of file names that contains three substrings that I want to order on. The files names are formatted as such:

```
MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2
```

I want to order this list firstly on MAF substring, then MHC substring, then S substring, such that the order is:

```
MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2
```

I have had a play around with gsub after seeing the answer to this question regarding a single substring: 
[R Sort strings according to substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542690/r-sort-strings-according-to-substring)

But I am not sure how to extend this idea to multiple substrings (of mixed character and numerical classes) within a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner in base R:

```
bar <- foo[order(sapply(strsplit(foo, "\\."), function(x) paste(x[1], x[4])))]
head(data.frame(result = bar), 10)

                          result
1          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
2  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
3           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
4          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
5  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
6           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
7          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
8  MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
9           MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
10         MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
```

Explanation:

- Split string by `.` using `strsplit`: `strsplit(foo, "\\.")`
- Extract and combine elements 1 and 4: `paste(x[1], x[4])`
- Get order of all combinations using `order`
- Get corresponding value from `foo[]`

---

Data (`foo`):

```
c("MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1", 
"MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2", 
"MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", 
"MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", 
"MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", 
"MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1", 
"MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. And thank you for the explanation. I am presuming this is automatically ordering by the MHC substring as R already has this substring in the order I want it in?

Comment: `strsplit(foo, '.', fixed = TRUE)` would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(filenames = c(...))

pattern = "^([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)"
df %>%
  extract(filenames, 
          into = c("maf", "mhc"), 
          regex = pattern, remove = FALSE) %>%
  arrange(maf, mhc) %>%
  select(filenames)
```

Which yields

```
                       filenames
1          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
2          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
3           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
4           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
5  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
6  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
7          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
8          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
9           MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
10          MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
11 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
12 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
13         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
14         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
15          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
16          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2
17 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
18 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
```

Answer (score 1):

This result match your desired output, but it only sorts according to `MAF` and `S`. I didn't understand how to use `MHC` string for sorting, please elaborate a bit on that part if this answer doesn't meet your needs.

```
library(stringr)
maf <- str_extract(filenames, "MAF\\d+\\.")
mhc <- str_extract(filenames, "\\..*MHC.*\\.")
s <- str_extract(filenames, "S\\d+$")

library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(filenames, maf, mhc, s) %>% 
  arrange(maf, s) %>% 
  select(filenames)
```

the output is:

```
                       filenames
1          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
2          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
3           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
4           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
5  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
6  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
7          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
8          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
9           MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
10          MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
11 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
12 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
13         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
14         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
15          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
16          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2
17 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
18 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
```

where `filenames` is

```
filenames <- read.table(text="MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many good solutions have already been added here. I'm adding another one which is based on use of `vector` only.

**Note:** `OP` intended to sort on `MAF`, `MHC` and `S` substrings. I have stick with that rule to sort all three. Hence result of my answer may not match with other answers.

The approach:

1. Use `regmatches` to find substrings per description in OP
2. Use `paste` to prepare strings based on which `sort` can be performed
3. Set names of vector using `setNames`
4. Sort `vector` on name.

   ```
   v[order(names(setNames(v, 
         paste(regmatches(v, regexpr("^MAF\\d+", v, perl = TRUE)),
               regmatches(v, regexpr("\\w*MHC\\w*", v, perl = TRUE)),
               regmatches(v, regexpr("\\w+\\d+$", v, perl = TRUE))
              ))))]
   #Result
   [1] "MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [2] "MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [3] "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [4] "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [5] "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1"
   [6] "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2"
   [7] "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [8] "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [9] "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [10] "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [11] "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1"
   [12] "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2"
   [13] "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [14] "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [15] "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1"
   [16] "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
   [17] "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1"
   [18] "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2"
   ```

**data**

```
v <- c("MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1", 
       "MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2", 
       "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1", 
       "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2", 
       "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1", 
       "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function designed especially for such a task:

**function**

```
reg_sort <- function(x,...,verbose=F) {
    ellipsis <-   sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1], deparse, simplify="array")
    reg_list <-   paste0(ellipsis, collapse=',')
    reg_list %<>% strsplit(",") %>% unlist %>% gsub("\\\\","\\",.,fixed=T)
    pattern  <-   reg_list %>% map_chr(~sub("^-\\\"","",.) %>% sub("\\\"$","",.) %>% sub("^\\\"","",.) %>% trimws)
    descInd  <-   reg_list %>% map_lgl(~grepl("^-\\\"",.)%>%as.logical)

    reg_extr <-   pattern %>% map(~str_extract(x,.)) %>% c(.,list(x)) %>% as.data.table
    reg_extr[] %<>% lapply(., function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))

    map(rev(seq_along(pattern)),~{reg_extr<<-reg_extr[order(reg_extr[[.]],decreasing = descInd[.])]})

    if(verbose) { tmp<-lapply(reg_extr[,.SD,.SDcols=seq_along(pattern)],unique);names(tmp)<-pattern;tmp %>% print }

    return(reg_extr[[ncol(reg_extr)]])
}
```

**data:**

```
vec <- c("MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1", 
  "MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2", 
  "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", 
  "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1", "MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", 
  "MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2", 
  "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1", 
  "MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2", "MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2"
)
```

**call:**

```
reg_sort(x=vec, "^.*?(?=\\.)","(?<=\\.).*(?<=\\.S)","S\\d+$")
```

**result:** (a character vector)

```
1          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S1
2          MAF001.incMHC.zPGS.S2
3           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S1
4           MAF001.noMHC.zPGS.S2
5  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
6  MAF001.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
7          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S1
8          MAF002.incMHC.zPGS.S2
9           MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S1
10          MAF002.noMHC.zPGS.S2
11 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
12 MAF002.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
13         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S1
14         MAF003.incMHC.zPGS.S2
15          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S1
16          MAF003.noMHC.zPGS.S2
17 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S1
18 MAF003.noMHC_incRS148.zPGS.S2
```

**other features are:**

- Sort descending: (add `-` infront) `reg_sort(x=vec, -"^.*?(?=\\.)","(?<=\\.).*(?<=\\.S)",-"S\\d+$")`
- Verbose mode: `reg_sort(x=vec, "^.*?(?=\\.)","(?<=\\.).*(?<=\\.S)","S\\d+$",verbose=T)` (see/check what the regEx pattern has extracted in order to sort)